# Feels weird for the results of `fs.readFile` IO works in NodeJS thread pool

Tags: node.js, callback, threadpool, fs, event-loop

I generated lots of files with the same content and 150M size.
I use `fs.readFile` async API to read them like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const COUNT = 16;

for (let i = 1; i <= COUNT; ++i) {
    console.time(i);
    console.log(process.hrtime());
    fs.readFile(`a${i}`, (err, data) => {
        console.log(process.hrtime());
        console.timeEnd(i);
    });
}
```

I've set the ENV variable `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` to 1. And then changed the `COUNT` to 8, 16, even to 128.
But the callback seems triggered almost the same time. For 128, the time is more than 4s.

I've tested for just 1 file, it'll cost around 60ms. And this screenshot is the result for 8 files:

[image]

In my memory, the async `fs.readFile` API is handled by the thread pool. So I changed the pool size to 1.

And in NodeJS event loop, the poll phase will handle the IO event and execute the callback for them. I forgot how long the poll phase will block the event loop. But I guess it less than 4s.

So for the code above, we wanna read the files async. They are started at the same time, be queued and waiting for picking up. Since the poll size is 1, I guess we will read all the files one by one, right? And if one file has read, the callback will be executed in some next poll phase (For 128 files, the time is more than 4s, so I guess there will be a next poll phase). And then we will get the time in console.

But I don't understand the output. Seems the callbacks are triggered at almost the same time.

Am I wrong about the poll phase in the event loop or something about the thread pool?

---

Update: I know I can use the stream to optimize reading large files. But the question is about the async API seems like run parallel when I set thread pool to 1.

---

Update: Thanks for the answer from @O. Jones. He told me that nodejs interleaves those little chunks in reading files. Could anybody help me give me some resources about it? Or anyone knows other information?

Answer (score 1):

150 megabytes is a substantial amount of data, and so takes time to transfer from your disk or SSD into RAM. And it's likely that your disk or SSD has an internal read-request queue of some kind. When you request multiple near-simultaneous reads they go into that queue and are handled one after the other.

Reads of large files are broken up into smaller block reads. It looks like node interleaves those block reads, so multiple `readFile` operations proceed roughly in parallel.

In practice it's best to use streams to read files of that size. If you don't need all that data in RAM at once, streams are good because they fire `'data'` events for each chunk of data, and `'close'` events when done. See this https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll make a test about the multi `readFile` operations for large files.

Comment: I switch to some files with 1.2M. For 1 file, it will take around 5ms. For 8 files, the first is around 9ms and the others are around 6ms.

The interleave in node for the little chunks is really out of my knowledge. Thank you so much for it.

Could I find some articles or source for it? :)

Comment: Hi. I have thought about it again. In my memory, the tasks from events will be in a queue waiting for pick up. But the pool size is 1. So will there be multi reading?